# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin (nx)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cos (nx)$ are uniformly convergent iff $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges.

I have proved that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges then both the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin (nx)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cos (nx)$ are uniformly convergent by Weierstrass-M test. But I find difficulty to prove the other way round. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cos (nx)$ is converge then for $x=0$ is so.

Comment: @MyGlasses how do you convert $∑a_n < \infty$ into absolute summability?

Comment: $|a_n|^2=|a_n|^2\sin^2nx+|a_n|^2\cos^2nx\leq(|a_n\sin nx|+|a_n\cos nx|)^2$

Comment: @MyGlasses I don't see how to conclude $∑|a_n \sin(nx)| < \infty$ for any $x≠2kπ $ (or cosine) from the uniform convergence of $∑a_n \sin (nx) $ (or cosine) but I'll let OP ask for clarifications if he wants to.

Comment: Yes. I agree with Calvin Khor. Convergence of $\sum a_n$  does not imply absolute summability of it even by your second comment @MyGlasses. How can we say the absolute convergence of the series $\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ and $\sum a_n \cos (nx)$ from uniform convergence. The reasoning is not convincing to me. How do you get it. Please let me know clearly.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay: For the reverse direction, should one assume that **both**  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin (nx)$ **and** $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cos (nx)$ are uniformly convergent, or just one of them?

Comment: @Martin R you can assume that the convergence of both of the series are uniform on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If the sums about $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{2}a_{n}\sin(nx)$ and similar to the $\cos$ are uniformly convergent, then it goes through, but I fail to see how is it going on with just the given condition.

Comment: I think this must be false. You can write $z=e^{ix}$, and then you're dealing with functions $f(z)$ from the disk algebra with uniformly convergent Taylor series on $|z|\le 1$. These spaces have been studied, and I don't see it mentioned anywhere that $a\in\ell^1$ (also, the disk algebra contains functions with $a\notin\ell^1$ for sure). See here for example www.ams.org/proc/2000-128-06/S0002-S0002-9939-99-05361-7